# ArcTan[z] and ArcTan[x,y], Restriction and Conversion

Tags: functions, trigonometry

In *Mathematica* there are two different forms for the arctangent (inverse tangent), namely

```
ArcTan[x,y]
```

which gives the arc tangent of $y/x$, taking into account which quadrant the point $(x,y)$ is in, and

```
ArcTan[z]
```

which gives the arc tangent $\tan^{-1}(z)$ of the complex number $z$.

I am not sure about the exact conversion rule, but as far as I understand it is not simply

```
ArcTan[z] == ArcTan[x+I y] == ArcTan[x,y]
```

How do I restrict *Mathematica* to use only one of the two forms for `ArcTan`, or convert between the two?

**EDIT**

Maybe I should elucidate on the problem at hand.
I am trying to solve the equation
$$
    a \cos(x) + b \sin(x) = c
$$
which can be done with the *Weierstrass substitution* to yield
$$
x_{\pm} = 2 \arctan\left[ \frac{b \pm \sqrt{a^2+b^2 - c^2}}{a+c}\right]
$$
which is of the type `ArcTan[z]`. But if instead I use *Mathematica*

```
Solve[a Cos[x] + b Sin[x] == c, x]
```

Then I get an ugly expression of the type `ArcTan[x,y]`:

$$
\arctan\left[\frac{a c-\sqrt{a^2 b^2+b^4-b^2
   c^2}}{a^2+b^2},\frac{\frac{a \sqrt{-b^2
   \left(-a^2-b^2+c^2\right)}}{a^2+b^2}-\frac{a^2
   c}{a^2+b^2}+c}{b}\right]
$$

How do I tell *Mathematica* to convert this expression into an `ArcTan[z]` or vice versa?

(I purposely neglected the periodicity of the solutions.)

**EDIT 2**
I just saw, that `Reduce` yields an `ArcTan[z]`. Where is the logic behind this?

Comment: The conversion to Matlab using `ToMatlab` seems to be totally off, as `ArcTan[x,y] //ToMatlab` yields `atan(x,y)`, but should be `atan2(y,x)`.

Comment: `ToMatlab` is not a perfect package, and you'll find a lot of other errors, if you use it often enough. Re: "How do I restrict _Mathematica_ to use only one of the two forms" – well, you are the one calling the function, right? _Mathematica_ doesn't accidentally switch from a one argument version to two or vice versa unless you explicitly say so.

Answer (score 3):

```
Solve[a Cos[x] + b Sin[x] == c && t == Tan[x], t, {x}]
% /. (a_ -> b_) -> x -> ArcTan@b
```

[image]

```
a Cos[x] + b Sin[x] == c /. (f : (Sin | Cos))[x_] :> TrigExpand@f[2 ArcTan[x]]
Solve[%, x]
% /. (_ -> b_) -> x -> 2 ArcTan@b
```

[image]

Or

```
Solve[{a Cos[x] + b Sin[x] == c}, x, Method -> Reduce,  MaxExtraConditions -> All]
Solve[{a Cos[x] + b Sin[x] == c, a != 0, b != 0, c != 0}, x, 
  Reals, Method -> Reduce] // FullSimplify
```

Comment: This is very useful, thank you. However, I consider this only half the solution, because it only addresses the restriction part. What I still like to know is how to convert between the two `ArcTan` forms. If you could add this, I accept your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that according to definitions used in *Mathematica*, for all complex or real $x,y$ the following holds:

```
ArcTan[x, y] == 2 ArcTan[y/(x + Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])] == -I Log[(x + I y)/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]
```

Comment: The only issue is that for $\Re(x)<0,\,y=0,$ the expression in the middle `2 ArcTan[y/(x + Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])]` evaluates to `Indeterminate` rather than $\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica's documentation usually assumes you know the definitions of the mathematical functions it is implementing...which sometimes means doing research.

The vector from the origin to the point (x,y) makes an angle arctan(y/x) with the positive x axis. In the complex plane, this corresponds to arg(x+iy).

`ArcTan[y/x] == ArcTan[y/x+I 0]`

`ArcTan[x,y] == Arg[x+I y]`

`ArcTan[z]` uses the definition `f[z]=Log[(1 + I z)/(1 - I z)]/(2 I)` subject to branch cut discontinuities along the imaginary axis extending to infinity from +i or -i. (i.e. no branch cut between +i and -i).

The effect of these branch cuts is:

1)Along the positive imaginary axis beyond +i,

`ArcTan[z]==f[z]`

2)Along the negative axis beyond -i,

`ArcTan[z] == -Re[f[z]] + Im[f[z]]`.

I came to these conclusions after looking at a plot of `Boole[ArcTan[x+I y]==f[x+I y]]` which seems to imply agreement everywhere except along the imaginary axis. I then compared the numerical values given at points along the y axis from -10,10 to come up with the effect of the branch cuts.