# Mathematica's ArcTan function

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to calculate the angle made by a vector from two vector components but am having some trouble. The x-component has a magnitude of -2.7388321862151737*^10 and the y-component has a magnitude of 1.4452659458183087*^11. Now, using the ArcTan function I have:

```
a = ArcTan[1.4452659458183087`*^11/-2.7388321862151737`*^10]/Degree
```

But this gives me an answer of -79.2695 degrees which lies in the 4th Quadrant, and I would have thought that it should have made an angle lying in the 2nd Quadrant (i.e. between 90 and 270 degrees). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you read the [`ArcTan` documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ArcTan.html)?

Comment: Thanks gpap, I appreciate your help.

Comment: May be this is a silly question but you say that "One line lies along the x-axis.. and the other lies along the y-axis" so aren't they supposed to be perpendicular to each other? Also if theta is the angle between ur two lines then 180-theta would be the supplementary angle.

Comment: It's true as Hubble07 says, you're not calculating the angle between the lines, you're calculating the angle between the hypotenuse of the right sided triangle formed by those two catheti. Using the documentation, we can see that it should be written `ArcTan[x,y]`: `ArcTan[-2.7388321862151737`*^10, 1.4452659458183087`*^11]/Degree` which returns `100.731`.

Comment: Yup the lines are perpendicular to each other but their magnitudes are different. Think of it like x- and y-components of a vector: the components are always perpendicular to each other, but depending on their magnitudes they can make vectors with different angles relative to a Cartesian coordinate system.

Comment: This issue is not with mathematicas arctan, but with your misunderstanding of basic trig. The angle will be given by the arcCos[] of the dot product, which will yield exactly Pi/2.

Comment: @george2079, I don't think you understand. Yes the x- and y-components make an angle of pi/2 radians to each other, BUT the vector made up of these two components will not. That's why I'm using the ArcTan function.

Comment: Well then your phrasing of the question is quite wrong, suggest you edit the question to say what you actually mean.

Comment: Duly noted and changed.

Answer (score 7):

Another way, not found in nor appropriate to the proposed duplicate, [ArcTan[z] and ArcTan[x,y], Restriction and Conversion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34617/arctanz-and-arctanx-y-restriction-and-conversion), is

```
myArcTan[x_Real] := Piecewise[{{Pi + ArcTan[x], x < 0}}, ArcTan[x]]

myArcTan[1.4452659458183087`*^11/-2.7388321862151737`*^10]/Degree
(* 100.731 *)
```

More generally, if you're willing to let the function have arbitrary arguments, we can specify an arbitrary range for the real part of the value of arc tangent.  We need to define a custom `Mod` that will apply only to the real part of the input.

```
Clear[myArcTan, reMod];
reMod[m_, n_, d_] := Mod[Re@m, n, d] + Im[m] I;
myArcTan::range = "The range `` must have length Pi.";
myArcTan[x_, range_List: {-Pi/2, Pi/2}] /; 
   If[range[[2]] - range[[1]] == Pi, True, Message[myArcTan::range, range]; False] := 
  reMod[ArcTan[x], Pi, range[[1]]];
```

**Examples**

The standard `ArcTan`.

```
myArcTan[1.4452659458183087`*^11/-2.7388321862151737`*^10]/Degree
(* -79.2695 *)
```

The OP's desired range `{0, Pi}`.

```
myArcTan[1.4452659458183087`*^11/-2.7388321862151737`*^10, {0, Pi}]/Degree
(* 100.731 *)
```

Error checking.

```
myArcTan[1.4452659458183087`*^11/-2.7388321862151737`*^10, {0, Pi/2}]/Degree
```

> myArcTan::range: The range {0,[Pi]/2} must have length Pi.

```
(* myArcTan[-5.27694, {0, \[Pi]/2}]/\[Degree] *)
```

Listability is inherited.  Note the discontinuity at `0` if the range is `{0, Pi}`.

```
myArcTan[Range[-10., 10, 2], {0, Pi}]/Degree
(* {95.7106, 97.125, 99.4623, 104.036, 116.565,
    0., 63.4349, 75.9638, 80.5377, 82.875, 84.2894} *)
```

Arbitrary expressions.  Note that symbolic expressions do not simplify easily.

```
myArcTan[N@{{1, 2}, 3 I, {{x}}}, {0, Pi}]
(* {{0.785398, 1.10715}, 1.5708 + 0.346574 I,
    {{I Im[ArcTan[x]] + Mod[Re[ArcTan[x]], \[Pi], 0]}}} *)

(* Check *)
Tan[%] // Simplify
(* {{1., 2.}, 4.89859*10^-16 + 3. I,
    {{I Tanh[Im[ArcTan[x]] - I Mod[Re[ArcTan[x]], \[Pi], 0]]}}} *)
```