# Discontinuity problem with 3D cylindrical heat equation (possibly due to a conversion between Cartesian to Cylindrical coordinates)

Tags: finite-element-method, discontinuity, heat-equation

I have been working a certain type of 3D cylindrical diffusion equation for a bit now. I am trying to simulate a longitudinal diffusion process in a cylinder with a dislocation defect that will make the heat flow spiral upward as you can see underneath with these two animations :

[image: spiraling diffusion process]
[image: same simulation but with a reduced PlotRange for a better view of the process][image: from the left side (ViewPoint -> {3, 0, 0})]

Here you can find the code I used to simulate an upward diffusion process along a cylinder.

```
(*parameters*)
r0 = 0.5;
r1 = 1;
h = 10;
\[Beta] = 1;


(*arg[z_]/;Im[z]<0:=Arg[z]+2 \
Pi;arg[z_]/;Im[z]\[GreaterEqual]0:=Arg[z]  possible alternative to \
Mod[Artan[x,y],2Pi]*)

(*region definition*)
reg = Cuboid[{r0, 0., 0.}, {r1, 2 Pi, h}];

reg3D = ImplicitRegion[
   r0^2 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && 0 <= z <= h, {x, y, z}];

(*equation + conditions*)
eq3 = D[u[t, r, \[Theta], z], 
    t] - (D[u[t, r, \[Theta], z], r, r] + (1/r)*
      D[u[t, r, \[Theta], z], r] + 
     1/(r^2)*D[
       u[t, r, \[Theta], 
        z], \[Theta], \[Theta]] + (r^2 + \[Beta]^2)/(r^2)*
      D[u[t, r, \[Theta], z], z, z] - (2 \[Beta]^2/r^2) D[
       u[t, r, \[Theta], z], z, \[Theta]]);


ic = u[0, r, \[Theta], z] == 1;
bc = DirichletCondition[u[t, r, \[Theta], z] == 0, z == 0];
nV = NeumannValue[0, r == r1] + NeumannValue[0, r == r0] + 
   NeumannValue[1, z == h];

(*solution computation*)
sol = NDSolveValue[{eq3 == nV, ic, bc}, 
   u, {t, 0, 5}, {r, \[Theta], z} \[Element] reg];

frames = Table[
   DensityPlot3D[
    sol[t, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], 
     Mod[Arctan[x, y], 2 Pi],z], {x, y, z} \[Element] reg3D, 
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", OpacityFunction -> None, 
    Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50,
     PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", t}], 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False], {t, .05, 5, .05}];

Export["better view all.mov", frames]
```

As you can see with these animations, there seem to be a discontinuity on the left side of the cylinder. This discontinuity left me quite puzzled as I could not find any physical explanation. The equation itself does not hint at any kind of irregularities with respect to theta. The solution should be continuous around the cylinder, especially if we imagine that the solution represents temperature for instance, then such behavior would be prohibited.

After discussing this with some other people, I remembered a very simple fact that I had totally missed. The discontinuity I was trying hard to explain could simply come from the `Arctan[x,y]` function I was using when I tried to animate the whole diffusion process.

I tried using other alternatives, for instance, I tried using  `Mod[Arctan[y/x],2Pi]` instead but it gave me the following animation.

[image: same animation but with Mod[Arctan[y/x],2Pi]]

At least I now know that it's the conversion between cartesian and polar coordinates that gives me such a peculiar discontinuity.

I also tried using the `Arg` function and even tried building one that goes from 0 to 2Pi following  the answers found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45953/getting-argz-to-go-from-0-to-2-pi). However it pretty much gave me the same result as with `Mod[Arctan[x,y],2Pi]`.

I searched for some similar questions asked here regarding the Arctan function and found [this question here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35553/mathematicas-arctan-function) showing us how to build a version of Arctan that could potentially help me here. However it was fruitless in the end as the simulation failed this time and gave me a blank video showing a white background.

Eventually I was very interested in how the discontinuity in the Arctan function was bypassed in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121388/problem-using-arctan-inside-ndsolve) by using the derivative of said function and then integrating when needed, however I am still working on that lead (I'm still a beginner when it comes to Mathematica alright...).

In the end, I'm fairly sure that it isn't a "physical discontinuity" but instead is induced by my own algorithm but I would like to know your opinion on that matter as I could very well be wrong from the start.
And if so, is there a way for me to possibly get a nice simulation without such a discontinuity ?

I would really appreciate the help, even just tiny hints. Thanks in advance.

**Edit** : Thanks the advice of user xzczd, I revised my code so that It contains periodic boundary conditions, following the example given [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/220363/1871) using double pbcs and ghost vicinity.
I now have the following code :

```
(*parameters*)
r0 = 0.5;
r1 = 1;
h = 5;
\[Beta] = .5;

(*Ghost vivinity parameter*)
epsilon = 0;


(*region definition*)
reg = Cuboid[{r0, -2 Pi - epsilon, 0.}, {r1, 2 Pi + epsilon, h}]; 

reg3D = ImplicitRegion[
   r0^2 <= x^2 + y^2 <= r1 && 0 <= z <= h, {x, y, z}];

(*Diffusion equation*)
eq = D[u[t, r, \[Theta], z], 
    t] - (D[u[t, r, \[Theta], z], r, r] + (1/r)*
      D[u[t, r, \[Theta], z], r] + 
     1/(r^2)*D[
       u[t, r, \[Theta], 
        z], \[Theta], \[Theta]] + (r^2 + \[Beta]^2)/(r^2)*
      D[u[t, r, \[Theta], z], z, z] - (2 \[Beta]^2/r^2) D[
       u[t, r, \[Theta], z], z, \[Theta]]);

(*Initial and boundary conditions*)
ic = u[0, r, \[Theta], z] == 1;
bc = DirichletCondition[u[t, r, \[Theta], z] == 0, 
   z == 0];
pbc={PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[t,r,\[Theta],z],\[Theta]\
\[Equal]2Pi+epsilon&&0<z<h,TranslationTransform[{0,-2Pi,0}]\
],PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[t,r,\[Theta],z],\[Theta]\[Equal]0-\
epsilon&&0<z<h,TranslationTransform[{0,2Pi,2Pi*\[Beta]0e[0, r == r0] + 
   NeumannValue[1, z == h];

(*solution computation*)
sol = NDSolveValue[{eq == nV, ic, bc(*,pbc*)}, 
   u, {t, 0, 15}, {r, \[Theta], z} \[Element] reg];


(*Animation of the diffusion process*)
frames = Table[
   DensityPlot3D[
    sol[t, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], Mod[ArcTan[x, y], 2 Pi], 
     z], {x, y, z} \[Element] reg3D, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
    OpacityFunction -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
    PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", t}],
     ColorFunctionScaling -> False], {t, .05, 15, .05}];

Export["beta=1.mov", frames]
```

This new code allows me to get a nice continuous animation, at the expense of the spiraling motion, however,  which completely defeats the purpose...

[image]

I really don't know what to do now.

Comment: I think you are missing the z variable in your frames expression.  Shouldn't it be `sol[t, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], Mod[ArcTan[x, y], 2 Pi], z]`?

Comment: Periodic b.c. is missing. You may want to read this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/239231/1871

Comment: The [Heat Transfer PDE tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransfer.html) has a section on "Heat Equation in Cylindrical Coordinates" which has a links to a Verification examples with cylindrical coordinates. For example [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransferVerificationTests.html#932720679)

Comment: @TimLaska Yes you are right, I rewrote the Mod[Arctan...] part when I created this post and accidentally deleted the z. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: @xzczd I have tried using periodic b.c before. I had these as my conditions :

````bc = {DirichletCondition[u[t, r, \[Theta], z] == 0, z == 0], 
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[t, r, \[Theta], z], \[Theta] == 0, 
    TranslationTransform[{0, 2 Pi, 0}]]};````

However the simulation would not run and gave me this instead :

````NDSolveValue::femnodpbc: DirichletCondition can not be present on the target boundary of a PeriodicBoundaryConditon.````

Comment: @user21 Thank you for your answer. I will examine the link you gave me.

Comment: You haven't set `PeriodicBoundaryCondition` properly. Try `PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[t, r, \[Theta], z], \[Theta] == 0 && 0 < z < h, 
 TranslationTransform[{0, 2 Pi, 0}]]`. Also, you need 2 `PeriodicBoundaryCondition`. For more info please check the answer linked in my last comment.

Comment: @xzczd I was just reading the link you advised me to look at. I understand now that my periodic b.c. condition was ill-defined and that I need two of them. I am unsure whether or not I need to use Triangle elements in my case, I haven't finished reading nor fully understanding the page.

For now, I have tried to implement 
`{PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[t, r, \[Theta], z], \[Theta] == 0 && 0 < z < h,   TranslationTransform[{0, 2 Pi, 0}]],PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[t, r, \[Theta], z], \[Theta] == 2 Pi && 0 < z < h,   TranslationTransform[{0, -2 Pi, 0}]]}`
I hope it works...

Comment: @xzczd I thank you for your guidance, however it seems that I still can't get the code to run properly.  It seems that I'm once again doing something wrong. Here is the code I corrected (after including the two PBCs)

`sol = NDSolveValue[{eq3 == nV, ic, bc}, 
   u, {t, 0, 5}, {r, \[Theta], z} \[Element] reg, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "MeshOptions" -> {"MeshElementType" -> "TriangleElement"}}];`

I get greeted with `NDSolveValue::femtemedm: TriangleElement is not a mesh element for a dimension 3 element mesh.` 
I once again need your enlightenment on this matter.

Comment: Oops, it's my mistake. I forgot `TriangleElement` is only for spatially 2D problem. Now ghost vicinity as shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/220363/1871) seems to be the only choice. Also, since your domain is regular, the old good `TensorProductGrid` is also a possible choice. (It's much easier to set periodic b.c. when `TensorProductGrid` method is chosen. )

Comment: @xzczd After adding some ghost vicinity, I no longer have any errors up to the part where I try to animate the whole process (I put the full code in an edit, up above). However I get new errors like `Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.`when generating "frames" before exporting it. 
 Do I also need to change "reg3D" so that it can accomodate for the ghost vicinity ?

Comment: `Arctan` should be `ArcTan`. After correcting this, I cannot reproduce the mentioned warning, at least in _v12.2_.

Comment: @xzczd To think that I couldn't get it to work again due to such a simple mistake. Thank you for pointing this out. 
I finally have an animation with no discontinuity, although I seemingly lost the whole "spiraling" motion in the process, which kinds of defeat the purpose. 



The spiraling process should be so that when you make a 2Pi rotation, you would have "risen" of a 2Pi*beta lenght. So perhaps I should try 
`PeriodicBoundaryCondition[
 u[t, r, \[Theta], z], \[Theta] == 2 Pi + epsilon && 0 < z < h, 
 TranslationTransform[{0, -2 Pi, -2 Pi*\[Beta]}]]`  instead... I'll try that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The end goal is to create a visualization of heat flow that spirals in a helical fashion due to a dislocation defect. The OP's initial attempt was to formulate the problem and cylindrical coordinates, which led to difficulty achieving the desired visual effects.

This answer proposes a Cartesian coordinate approach that may be irrelevant, but it will produce a spiraling heat diffusion effect.

## Bilayered screw

I prototyped the model in SolidWorks by sweeping two rectangular slabs along a helical path as shown below.

[image: SolidWorks image]

If we step through a Z clip plane, we can see two semi disks spiraling. This is simple enough geometry that we should be able to construct a solvable mesh.

[image: SolidWorks screw animation]

## Helper functions

In addition to the FEM package, we will use MeshTools to extrude a quadrilateral disk mesh. We will apply a small twist to the mesh as we move up the Z direction.

```
(*Import required FEM package*)
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
(*Install MeshTools*)
(*Uncomment if not installed*)
(*ResourceFunction["GitHubInstall"]["c3m-labs","MeshTools"]*)
Needs["MeshTools`"]
(*Wrap twisted mesh builder function in module*)
Clear[buildMeshes]
buildMeshes[rad_, nrad_, ht_, θ_, turns_] := 
 Module[{nelm, mesh2D, mesh3D, Ω3Dright, rmf, 
   regmarkerfn, inc, mean,
   regmarkers, newcrd, mesh, vis2D, vis3D, visTwisted},
  nelm = 360 ° turns/θ;
  mesh2D = DiskMesh[{0, 0}, rad, nrad];
  vis2D = Show[
    mesh2D["Wireframe"],
    Graphics[{Point[mesh2D["Coordinates"]]}]
    ];
  mesh3D = ExtrudeMesh[mesh2D, nelm, nelm];
  (*Right RegionMember Function*)
  Ω3Dright = Cuboid[{0, -rad, 0}, {rad, rad, nelm}];
  rmf = RegionMember[Ω3Dright];
  regmarkerfn = If[rmf[#], reg["right"], reg["left"]] &;
  (*Get mean coordinate of each hexa for region marker assignment*)
  inc = ElementIncidents[mesh3D["MeshElements"]];
  mean = Mean /@ GetElementCoordinates[mesh3D["Coordinates"], #] & /@ 
     inc // First;
  regmarkers = regmarkerfn /@ mean;
  inc = inc[[1]];
  (*Create element mesh*)
  mesh3D = 
   ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> mesh3D["Coordinates"], 
    "MeshElements" -> {HexahedronElement[inc, regmarkers]}];
  vis3D = mesh3D[
     "Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "MeshElements", 
       "MeshElementStyle" -> (Directive[Opacity[0.5], 
          FaceForm[#]] &  /@ {Red, White}), 
     ViewPoint -> {-1.5, 0.8, -3}, ViewVertical -> {0, 1, 0}, 
       PlotRange -> All]];
  newcrd = 
   mesh3D["Coordinates"] /. {{x_, y_, 
       z_} -> {x Cos[z θ] - y Sin[z θ], 
       y Cos[z θ] + x Sin[z θ], z/nelm ht}};
  (*Create twisted mesh*)
  mesh = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> newcrd, 
    "MeshElements" -> {HexahedronElement[inc, regmarkers]}];
  visTwisted = mesh[
     "Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "MeshElements", 
       "MeshElementStyle" -> (Directive[Opacity[1], FaceForm[#](*, 
                 EdgeForm[]*)] &  /@ {Red, White}), 
     ViewPoint -> {2.5, -1.75, -1.7}, 
     ViewVertical -> {-0.2, 0.13, -0.97},
       PlotRange -> All]];
  <|"mesh2D" -> mesh2D, "mesh3D" -> mesh3D, "twistedMesh" -> mesh,
   "vis2D" -> vis2D, "vis3D" -> vis3D, "visTwisted" -> visTwisted|>
  ]
```

## A small coarse test example

We will test the `buildMeshes` function on a single turn with a large twist angle to produce a candy cane type structure.

```
(*Association for Clearer Region Assignment*)
reg = <|"left" -> 1, "right" -> 2|>;
(*Set parameters*)
rad = 1;
ht = 1;
θ = 20 °;
turns = 1;
nrad = 6;
meshes = buildMeshes[rad, nrad, ht, θ, turns]
meshes["visTwisted"]
```

[image: Test mesh]

## Larger model

Now, we will build a five-turn model with finer discretization both in the radial and theta direction.

```
(*Set parameters*)
rad = 1;
ht = 2;
θ = 5 °;
turns = 5;
nrad = 12;
meshes = buildMeshes[rad, nrad, ht, θ, turns];
mesh = meshes["twistedMesh"];
```

## Heat transfer PDE system

The twistedMesh function produced a mesh that had element markers so that we can assign an element marker-based thermal conductivity.  In this case, we will make one of the materials 10 times less conductive than the other.  We will use the [`HeatTransferPDEComponent`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HeatTransferPDEComponent.html) (new in 12.2) to set up the PDE system.  We will apply a 1° temperature difference across the actual boundaries. For expediency, we will consider steady-state only.

```
(*Set material parameters*)
kleft = 1;
kright = 1/10;
k = 
  Evaluate[
   Piecewise[
    {
     {kleft, ElementMarker == reg["left"]},
      {kright, True}
     }]
   ];
(*Set up PDE system*)
vars = {Θ[x, y, z], {x, y, z}};
pars = <|"ThermalConductivity" -> {{k, 0, 0}, {0, k, 0}, {0, 0, k}}|>;
Γtop = 
  HeatTemperatureCondition[z == ht, vars, 
   pars, <|"SurfaceTemperature" -> 1|>];
Γbot = 
  HeatTemperatureCondition[z == 0, vars, 
   pars, <|"SurfaceTemperature" -> 0|>];
eqn = {HeatTransferPDEComponent[vars, pars] == 
   0, Γtop, Γbot}
```

## Solving and postprocessing

Before we solve the PDE system we will first inspect the material conductivity along the z-axis.

```
(*Create thermal conductivity interpolation function*)
Short[values = 
  Function[{x, y, z}, Piecewise[{{(kleft + kright)/2, Abs[x] < 0.001},
      {kleft, x < 0},
      {kright, True}}]] @@@ meshes["mesh3D"]["Coordinates"]]
kif = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, values];
framesK = 
  SliceContourPlot3D[
     kif[x, y, z], {z == # ht}, {x, y, z} ∈ mesh, 
     ViewPoint -> {Infinity, Infinity, Infinity}, 
     ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
     Contours -> 13] & /@ (Subdivide[0, 1, 50]~Join~
     Subdivide[1, 0, 50]);
ListAnimate@framesK
```

[image: Material conductivity animation]

Now, we will look at the temperature solution. Since this is a steady-state solution, the temperature gradients are quite small so we will rescale the temperature at each clipping plane.

```
(*Solve and plot solution*)
Tfun = NDSolveValue[eqn, Θ, {x, y, z} ∈ mesh];
frames = SliceContourPlot3D[
     Tfun[x, y, z], {z == # ht}, {x, y, z} ∈ mesh, 
     ViewPoint -> {Infinity, Infinity, Infinity}, 
     ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
     Contours -> 13] & /@ (Subdivide[0, 1, 50]~Join~
     Subdivide[1, 0, 50]);
ListAnimate@frames
```

[image: Temperature animation]

It will be interesting to look at the heat flux along the axis. To do so, it will be necessary to create a derived variable for the temperature gradient and multiply it by our previously derived variable for thermal conductivity.

```
(*Set up derived temperature gradient and flux variable*)
Clear[gradT, flux]
gradT[x_, y_, z_] = {Derivative[1, 0, 0][Tfun][x, y, z], 
   Derivative[0, 1, 0][Tfun][x, y, z], 
   Derivative[0, 0, 1][Tfun][x, y, z]};
flux[x_, y_, z_] = -kif[x, y, z] gradT[x, y, z];
frames2 = 
  Show[SliceVectorPlot3D[
      flux[x, y, z], {z == # ht}, {x, y, z} ∈ mesh, 
      PlotLabel -> N[# ht], Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, 
      ViewPoint -> {Infinity, Infinity, -Infinity}, 
      VectorScaling -> Automatic, VectorSizes -> {0.1, 2}, 
      VectorMarkers -> Placed["Arrow3D", "Start"], 
      VectorAspectRatio -> 0.15, VectorPoints -> 25],
     SliceContourPlot3D[
      kif[x, y, z], {z == # ht}, {x, y, z} ∈ mesh, 
      ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors", 
      Contours -> 13]] & /@ (Subdivide[0, 1, 50]~Join~
     Subdivide[1, 0, 50]);
ListAnimate@frames2
```

[image: Heat flux animation]

The heat flux is predominantly in the downward direction as expected. Maybe less expected, is the highest heat fluxes are confined to the interface and fall off rather quickly.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your very detailed answer. I do have one question though. If I would like to take a look at the time dependent solution, do I simply change what's inside this new function "HeatTransferPDEComponent" by adding a time t, and also remove the color recalling ?

Comment: Change the `vars` assignment to `vars = {\[CapitalTheta][t, x, y], t, {x, y}}`.  You will have to add an initial condition, and you may need to add a ramp function to avoid inconsistencies in the ICs and BCs.  See [240190](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/240190/61809) for more details.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the additional help and the link. I will definitely look into it.

Comment: I forgot to ask something else.
 if I understood correctly, the dislocation defect is represented here by a "visTwisted", which is caracterized by a set of parameter '[rad, nrad, ht, θ, turns]'. Can you please clarify what nrad and turns do ? Also, θ is the screw dislocation angle in this case right ? Thanks in advance.