# 1D-waveequation with absorbing boundary condition: FEM solution?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I try to simulate the special absorbing(?) boundary condition

```
`Derivative[1, 0][y][1, t] + Derivative[0, 1 ][y][1, t] == 0`
```

which only allows energy flow in positive x-direction.

I'm able to solve the problem using `TensorPorductGrid` and `MethodOfLines`:

```
sys = {D[y[x, t], {x, 2}] - D[y[x, t], {t, 2}] == 0,
y[x, 0] ==Which[ 4/10 <= x <= 5/10, 10 x - 4, 5/10 < x <= 6/10, 6 - 10 x,True, 0], 
Derivative[0, 1][y][x, 0] == 0 ,
y [0, t] == 0,
Derivative[1, 0][y][1, t] + Derivative[0, 1 ][y][1, t] == 0}

Y = NDSolveValue[sys, y, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2}, 
Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid","MaxPoints" -> 200, "MinPoints" -> 200, "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}}]

Plot3D[Y[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All,PlotPoints -> 100, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}]
```

[image]

But if I try to change the method to `"FiniteElement"`

```
Y = NDSolveValue[sys, y, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2}, 
Method -> {"MethodOfLines","TemporalVariable" -> t, 
"SpatialDiscretization" ->{"FiniteElement"}}]
```

Mathematica gives error message

"NDSolveValue::fembdnl: The dependent variable in NDSolve`y$1+(y^(1,0))[1,t]==0 in the boundary condition DirichletCondition[NDSolve`y$1+(y^(1,0))[1,t]==0,x==1.] needs to be linear."

which I don't understand.

The next attempt using `NeumannValue` also went wrong:

```
Y = NDSolveValue[{D[y[x, t], {x, 2}] - D[y[x, t], {t, 2}] == 
    NeumannValue[-Derivative[0, 1 ][y][1, t], x == 1],
   y[x, 0] == 
    Which[ 4/10 <= x <= 5/10, 10 x - 4, 5/10 < x <= 6/10, 6 - 10 x, 
     True, 0], Derivative[0, 1][y][x, 0] == 0 ,
   y [0, t] == 0
   }, y, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement" }}, MaxStepSize -> .1]
```

and gives the not understandable message `NDSolveValue::delpde: Delay partial differential equations are not currently supported by NDSolve.`

Is it possible to avoid these messages and solve the problem with FEM?

Thanks!

**solution**

The helpful answer and comments led me to the FEM solution

```
NDSolveValue[{-D[y[x, t], {x, 2}] +D[y[x, t], {t, 2}] == NeumannValue[-Derivative[0, 1][y][x, t], x == 1], 
y[x, 0] ==Which[4/10 <= x <= 5/10, 10 x - 4, 5/10 < x <= 6/10, 6 - 10 x, 
True, 0], 
Derivative[0, 1][y][x, 0] == 0, 
y[0, t] == 0}, y, {x, 0,1}, {t, 0, 2}, 
Method -> {"MethodOfLines","TemporalVariable" -> t, 
"SpatialDiscretization" ->{"FiniteElement","MeshOptions" ->{"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}}]
```

Comment: Strongly related, if not duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/224812/1871 Another example of setting ABC when FEM is chosen can be found here:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128527/1871 BTW the new-in-12.2 `NDSolve\`FEM\`GetInactivePDE` can be used to analyze what `NeumannValue` should be set, here's an example: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/245309/1871

Comment: @xzczd Thank you for your helpful comment &&links. Simple  mistakes caused the error in my last attempt(see my modified answer)

Comment: @xzczd Do you think it 's also possible to get a "pure" FEM-solution without "MethodOfLines"? Thanks.

Comment: The way for solving IVP with FEM is discussed here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/172972/1871 Notice it's not recommended to solve IVP with FEM as mentioned by user21 in the comment under that question.

Comment: Make sure to check the message ref pages for hints on the error message and how to avoid them, for example FEMDocumentation/ref/message/InitializeBoundaryConditions/fembdnl

Answer (score 7):

There is a function [AcousticAbsorbingValue](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AcousticAbsorbingValue.html) that does what you want. There is a detailed explanation of the usage and limitation of these type of boundary conditions in the [Acoustics in the time domain Monograph](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/Acoustics/AcousticsTimeDomain.html#481530965) and there is a similar version of that for the frequency domain. The monograph also includes a section on [Perfectly matched layers (PMLs)](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/Acoustics/AcousticsTimeDomain.html#82427960) that are a better way to simulate infinite domains in some cases.

The third example from the scope section of [AcousticAbsorbingValue](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AcousticAbsorbingValue.html):

Define model variables vars for a transient acoustic pressure field with model parameters pars:

```
vars = {p[t, x], t, {x}};
pars = <|"SoundSpeed" -> 343, "MassDensity" -> 1.2|>;
```

Set up initial conditions ics of a right-going plane wave Subscript[p, 0]:

```
p0 = D[0.125 Erf[(x - 0.5)/0.15], x];
ics = {p[0, x] == p0, Derivative[1, 0][p][0, x] == -343*D[p0, x]};
```

Set up the equation with an acoustic absorbing boundary at the right end for a plane wave:

```
eqn = AcousticPDEComponent[vars, pars] == 
   AcousticAbsorbingValue[x == 1, vars, pars];
```

Solve the PDE:

```
pfun = NDSolveValue[{eqn, ics}, p, {t, 0, 0.003}, 
   x \[Element] Line[{{0}, {1}}]];
```

Visualize the solution:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[pfun[t, x], {x, 0, 1}, Sequence[
  PlotRange -> {-0.5, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "P"}]], {{t, 0.0013}, 0, 
  0.003, 10^-4}, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[pfun[t, x], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 0.003}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much , the links are very interesting! The equation `eqn`  corresponds to my last attempt. This gives me hope to still find the reason for the error message.

Comment: I modified my last attempt to `NeumannValue[-Derivative[0, 1 ][y][x, t], x== 1]` which changed the message to `Derivatives of dependent variables in boundary conditions are not \
supported with the Finite Element Method in this version of NDSolve`. This seems cleverly solved in the   [AcousticAbsorbingValue](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AcousticAbsorbingValue.html)