# Periodic boundary condition conflicts with DirichletCondition?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I want to solve a simple diffuse equation in a cylinder.

$\nabla\cdot(\hat{c}\nabla\rho_P）=0$

$\rho_P(x,y,\theta)==0,\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=R$

$\rho_P(0,0,\theta)==1,\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=0$

$\rho_P(x,y,2\pi)=\rho_P(x,y,0)$

$\hat{c}=\begin{pmatrix}  D_t& 0& 0 \\ 0 & D_t &0\\0 &0 &D_r \end{pmatrix}
\quad$

$D_t: transportation\ coefficient$

$D_r: rotation\ coefficient$

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

{R, Difft, Diffr} = {29.5, 1, 0.01};
\[CapitalOmega] = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2 \[Pi]}}, R];

c = {{Difft, 0, 0}, {0, Difft, 0}, {0, 0, Diffr}};

With[{rhop = rhop[x, y, \[Theta]]}, 
  op1 = Div[c . Grad[rhop, {x, y, \[Theta]}], {x, y, \[Theta]}]];

Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], D1] = 
  DirichletCondition[rhop[x, y, \[Theta]] == 1, 
   x^2 + y^2 == 0 && \[Theta] != 2 \[Pi]];
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], D2] = 
  DirichletCondition[rhop[x, y, \[Theta]] == 0, 
   x^2 + y^2 > 0 && \[Theta] != 0 && \[Theta] != 2 \[Pi]];
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], p] = 
  PeriodicBoundaryCondition[rhop[x, y, \[Theta]], \[Theta] == 2 \[Pi],
    Function[\[Theta], \[Theta] - 2 \[Pi]]];

cylinderMesh = 
  ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega], "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.04];

npfun = NDSolveValue[{op1 == 0, Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], p], 
    Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], D1], Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], D2]}, 
   rhop, {x, y, \[Theta]} \[Element] cylinderMesh];

ContourPlot[npfun[x, y, 2 \[Pi]], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[{0, 0}, R], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

Obviously, it is a symmetrical function, but when I solve it using  `NDSolveValue`, the result is not symmetric.
[image]

I think I can solve it by adding

```
additionalPoints = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2 \[Pi]}}
cylinderMesh = 
  ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega], "IncludePoints" -> additionalPoints];
```

But the error:
[image]
无法产生网络：enable to generate mesh

Comment: Your second DirichletCondition should be `Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], D2] = 
  DirichletCondition[rhop[x, y, \[Theta]] == 0, 
   x^2 + y^2 ==R^2 && \[Theta] != 0 && \[Theta] != 2 \[Pi]]`

Comment: Region `Cylinder`  suggest a 3D problem, but I'm missing an axial `z` coordinate!?

Comment: but,if i write as `Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], D1] = 
  DirichletCondition[rhop[x, y, \[Theta]] == 1, 
   x^2 + y^2 == 0 && \[Theta] != 0 && \[Theta] != 2 \[Pi]];`,  `Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], D2] = 
  DirichletCondition[rhop[x, y, \[Theta]] == 0, 
   x^2 + y^2 == R^2 && \[Theta] != 0 && \[Theta] != 2 \[Pi]];` there is a error: `NDSolveValue::bcnop: No position was found on the boundary where x^2+y^2==0&&\[Theta]!=0&\[Theta]!=2 \[Pi] is true, so DirichletCondition[rhop==1,x^2+y^2==0&&\[Theta]!=0&&[Theta]!=2 \[Pi]]. will be ignored `

Comment: I think I should add a line(0,0,theta) or points(0,0,2pi)(0,0,0) to the mesh, but i can't find the option.

Comment: Is `\[Theta` the axial coordinate(not an angle of polarcoordinates)?

Comment: yes, `z` is `theta`

Comment: The problem is not well-posed. `Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], D2]` already determines the solution, you cannot force b.c. at `x^2+y^2==0`, because it's the removable singularity in cylindrical coordinates. Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/245195/laplaces-equation-in-spherical-coordinates-with-neumann-b-c/245309#comment617526_245309

Answer (score 2):

I modified your code a little bit. You need two periodic boundaryconditions with
correct TranslationTransform in all coordinates. Additionally I force `NDSolve` to use `FiniteElement`- Method (no need to load `Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]`)

I changed the Region `\[CapitalOmega]` to avoid singularity `x^2+y^2->0`. Play around with the new small parameter `dR`.

It is often recommended to rationalize the parameters.

```
{R, dR, Difft, Diffr} = {29.5, 29.5/100, 1, 0.01}// Rationalize[#, 0]&;
\[CapitalOmega] =RegionDifference[Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2 \[Pi] }},R], Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2 \[Pi] }}, dR]];
```

Try

```
c = {{Difft, 0, 0}, {0, Difft, 0}, {0, 0, Diffr}};

With[{rhop = rhop[x, y, \[Theta]]},op1 = Div[c . Grad[rhop, {x, y, \[Theta]}], {x, y, \[Theta]}]];

\[CapitalGamma]D1 =DirichletCondition[rhop[x, y, \[Theta]] == 1,x^2 + y^2 == dR^2 && 0 < \[Theta] < 2 \[Pi]];
\[CapitalGamma]D2 =DirichletCondition[rhop[x, y, \[Theta]] == 0,x^2 + y^2 == R^2 && 0 < \[Theta] < 2 \[Pi]];
\[CapitalGamma]p = {PeriodicBoundaryCondition[rhop[x, y, \[Theta]], \[Theta] >= 2 \[Pi] &&dR^2 < x^2 + y^2 < R^2, TranslationTransform[{0, 0, -2 Pi}]],PeriodicBoundaryCondition[rhop[x, y, \[Theta]], \[Theta] <= 0 && dR^2 <x^2 + y^2 < R^2, TranslationTransform[{0, 0, +2 Pi}]]};


npfun = NDSolveValue[{op1 ==0, \[CapitalGamma]p, \[CapitalGamma]D1, \[CapitalGamma]D2}, rhop, {x, y, \[Theta]} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
Method -> {"FiniteElement"}]

reg = ImplicitRegion[dR^2 <= x^2 + y^2 <= R^2 , {x, y}]
Plot3D[ npfun[x, y,  \[Pi]]  , {x, y} \[Element] reg,PlotRange -> All , Mesh -> False]
```

[image]

`NDSolve` now evaluates a solution which is plausible.

The periodic boundary conditions are fullfiled quite well:

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[npfun[x, y, 2 \[Pi]] - npfun[x, y, 0]], {x, y}\[Element] reg,PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[Derivative[0, 0, 1][npfun][x, y, 2 \[Pi]] -Derivative[0, 0, 1][npfun][x, y, 0]], {x, y} \[Element] reg, PlotRange-> All]
```

[image]

I think you might get much better results if you formulate the underlying problem in "Cylindrical"-coordinates!